# Mix text and data to make a paragraph in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on a MS Access 2010 database where users proceed through several form pages of data entry and then are given the option to print a narrative report of the findings.

Some pages of the report have thing such as a text box that reads "Number of Widget A Sold:" and then next to it a Field for `WidgetASold` which is fine for that section. However, for one of the reports I would like this information integrated into a paragraph of text such as:-

> In this fiscal year we sold `WidgetASold` units of Widget A and `WidgetBSold` units of Widget B.

I have tried using VBA:-

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
Dim WidgetASold As String
Dim WidgetBSold As String
a = "In this fiscal year we sold "
b = " units of Widget A and "
c = " units of Widget B"
d = a & WidgetASold & b & WidgetBSold & c
```

Which I honestly don't even know if it is a good way to go about things. I have also considered having the text in its own table but I still wouldn't know how to get five fields to line up together in one paragraph.

Basically what I am looking for is the access equivalent of excel's

```
=CONCATENATE("Some text ",B2," more text ",B12," last text.")
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you use an expression as control source of a text box:

```
= "In this fiscal year we sold " & [WidgetASold] & " units of Widget A and " & [WidgetBSold] & " units of Widget B."
```

This assumes that `WidgetASold` and `WidgetBSold` are included in the record source of the report.

You *could* do it with VBA in the `On Format` event of the section, but there is really no reason to do so.